# ReportViewer without DataSet (.xsd), just SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, dataset, reportviewer, report, sqldatasource

Is there any way I can create a report without using (.xsd) DataSet? I don't want to go through that way, I want to use SqlDataSource.

Okay, so this is what I did so far.

1. I created a Report (.rdlc)
2. A page (.aspx)
3. On the page that I've created, I put a ReportViewer and SqlDataSource.

That's all, I don't know how to put them together.

Please help... I'm a newby...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has several pages with ReportViewer samples and walkthroughs:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252123%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251686.aspx

You don't have to use a DataSet; the ReportViewer data sources collection will take anything that is a collection, such as a list of objects. Here's just a couple more pages with examples:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ReportViewer.aspx
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1639831.aspx/1

Whenever I use the ReportViewer in local processing mode I use it in conjunction with a data mapper tool like iBatis and simply feed an `IList<Something>` of objects into it (wrapped in an ObjectDataSource).

Comment: Cory Larson, can you show me please a sample page (aspx) with SqlDataSource and ReportViewer? Can I do that without adding DataSet (.xsd)? Hm, so how am I going to create my Report (.rdlc)?